# How to check if .NET programmability support is installed for Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, .net-framework

I have to install third party software that requires that Microsoft Office 2007 be installed with "**.NET Programability Support**".

Does anyone know how I can tell if this was installed?

Comment: You should tag what operating system you're using to avoid getting a lot of incorrect answers.

Comment: Make sure you have .Net Framework installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Start, click Run, type appwiz.cpl, and then click OK.

In the list of installed programs and updates, click any Microsoft Office 2007 product, and then click Change.

In the list of update options for applications and tools, double-click any Microsoft Office 2007 product.

See if .NET Programmability Support appears to be installed already.

Comment: I didn't quit have the same options. When I clicked change I got "Add or Remove Features", "Repair", "Remove".

If I hit "Add or Remove Features" It shows a list of some things. But unable to tell what was installed or not.

Comment: So I just clicked install the programmability support. Hopefully this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Office Answers - Unable to install ".net programmability support" when installing office](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeinstall/thread/ebf7dffc-cddb-45b4-92c5-f4a6608a2624)

Once the add or remove program dialog box is open:

1. Select Microsoft Office.
2. Click on "change", you should see a few labelled icons, one will be the "net programmability support"
3. Click on the "+" sign to open it up.
4. If there is a red "X" then it is needs to be removed.

You can take it from here, use the link that is pasted (above) for your guide.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt Click on Setup.exe the instead of clicking on install now click on customize u would be able to see tree of components to be installed ,open tree of Microsoft Office Access the very first one is .NET Programmability Support if it has red Cross sign - X the it doesnot and if no sign the it does support.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly unchecked it, Office 2003 and above installed that by default. Office XP didn’t do it.

But you can also look for the interop libraries. Look for Excel.Interop.DLL (can’t remember the exact location but they are inside Program Files somewhere.